# Create the hierarchy rank of all employees given supervisor ID using Networkx

Tags: pandas, networkx

I have a dataframe in the following format

[image: employee dataframe]

I want to generate a new column which will tell me the rank of the employee in the company hierarchy. For example, the rank of the CEO is 0. Someone who reports directly to the CEO has a rank of 1. Someone just below that 2...and so on.

I have the supervisor ID for each employee. One employee can have only one supervisor. I have a feeling that I might be able to do this using Networkx, but I can't quite place how to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself. It's actually quite trivial.
I need to construct a graph, where the CEO is one of the nodes like every other employee.

```
import networkx as nx

# Create a graph using the networx builtin function
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'employeeId', 'supervisorId')

# Calculate the distance of the CEO from each employee. Sepcify target = CEO
dikt_rank_of_employees = { x[0]: x[1] for x in nx.single_target_shortest_path_length(
    G, target='c511b73c4ad30dde1b6d2d57ab2d4ddc') }

# Use this dictionary to create a column in the dataframe
df['rank_of_employee'] = df['employeeId'].map(dikt_rank_of_employees)
```

The result looks like this
[image]